# How to create a foreach that has 2 or more conditions in PHP with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

Hi how do I create a 2 foreach loop in php? I wanted to result the query with the Codeigniter format. But I'm having problem with the foreach loop here's the code for the query.

```
$query = $this -> db -> query("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS where CUSTOMER_ID IN (SELECT Customer_ID from Orders)");
$resultOrder = $this -> db -> query ("SELECT * FROM orders");
```

And I wanted to output this

```
foreach (array_merge($resultOrder->result(),$query->result()) as $row  )
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row -> Order_ID . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row -> First_Name . " " . $row ->Last_Name .  "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row-> Order_Date . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->Delivery_Date . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row -> Status . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row ->Remarks . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

But it has error. It says

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$First_Name
>   Filename: xxxx/xxxxxx.php
>   Line Number: xx

Thanks!

Edit:

Apparently it has an output but the output of `$row -> First_Name . " " . $row ->Last_Name` is separated to the others

Comment: it seems to be the case that one of your merged arrays has no entry called First_name

Comment: Learn about SQL joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a SQL join like this

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS c
left join orders o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
where CUSTOMER_ID IN (SELECT Customer_ID from Orders)
```